# fixing website to horizontal orientation on mobile devices (in simple terms)

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-orientation, mobile-devices

I am trying my hardest to create a webpage that when viewed on a mobile device automatically fixes to landscape orientation as opposed to portrait. It is a very simple page which at the moment just contains a video via iframe.

I have used code that I have found that was developed by somebody else. But I can not get it working at all. The code I am trying to implement is in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuynenue/9/).

Here is a [livelink](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/beach.html) of my attempt at getting this code to work. Could somebody please tell me why this code is not working?

Below is my code.

***CSS***

```
<style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; top: -15px;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%
        }
        html, body {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
body {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}    
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="content">
        <iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/qnca9gdlv5?videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="640" height="388"></iframe><script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js">    </script>
    </div>
```

code updated

Comment: I've recently encountered this issue in a hobby project and was surprised there isn't a solid answer (that I've found anyway). My problems were two-fold: `orientation:portrait` isn't recognized by some Android browsers, and I didn't want to trigger by a width value or look at userAgent. Secondly, device browsers (the apps themselves) are apparently programmed to know which way is down relative to the device. A rotate to the right is not the same as a rotate to the left. Web apps do not have access to things like the accelerometer, that i know of, so it got hacky, and i stalled out on the idea.

Comment: I believe the second issue is what you're seeing happen on your live link, at least it's happening on my Samsung Galaxy S4, in the Chrome app (usually closer to desktop and modern browsers than stock browser). The first issue is happening in the stock browser, where the `orientation:portrait` call is not recognized, and the body doesn't rotate at all.

Comment: @Dpeif hi, I am now getting somewhere. I have the rotation working however for some unknown reason, now my website starts off in landscape mode and when viewed on a mobile device is in portrait mode! the wrong way round! its as if its mocking me lol how do I fix this Please!!!